# How to print a message in console from a linux kernel call?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I want to modify a kernel call such as `SYS_FORK` in order to print my own messages in console. I tried to add a `printf` in the source code however when i try to recompile the kernel i am getting `string not expected` error. Somewhere i red about `printk` but this solution didn't work either! I'm still getting the same error message! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might like to show the modified code, and exact error message at least to help someone to answer this.

Comment: Also beware, adding a log statement to a widely used system call like `fork` will generate a tsunami of log messages and potentially harm your system.